# Is negative margins discouraged in CSS?

Tags: css

I want to expand subcontent of body content, and using negative margins. Related to standards, web browser compability and css-frameworks,  is this ok or discouraged?

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size:12px;
  margin:0px;
}

#page {
  max-width: 800px;
  padding:0.25rem 1rem;
}

#page h1 {
  margin:0.5rem 0rem;
  margin-bottom:0rem;
}

#page p {
  margin:0rem;
  padding:0.5rem 0rem;
}

.sub {
  margin:0.5rem -0.5rem;
  padding:0px;
}

.sub h2 {
  border:1px dashed #39c;
  padding:0.5rem;
  margin:0rem;
  color:#39c;
  border-radius:0.5rem;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
  <h1>Page title</h1>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae 

ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur 

aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
  <p> Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora 

incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis 

suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p>
  <div class="sub">
    <h2>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z</h2>
  </div>
  <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum 

fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum 

deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui 

officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero 

tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative margins are totally valid CSS as stated by W3C: "***Tip***: Negative values are allowed.."

They are supported by all modern browsers and can actually be a powerful tool if you understand how they work on specific positions.